# set timer inside a loop for graphql query

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, graphql

The thing I'm doing here is fetching anime characters from anilist graphql api. The reason I've added a loop is so I could fetch data from a certain character id to a limit. For example 1-100. But I want to respect their API rate limits and so I'd like a way to limit my requests to 1 per second. Hence, I've used `setTimeout`, but I still got rate-limited from the API and using `setInterval` only keeps on looping it every 5 seconds. Like the same data gets fetched every 5 seconds.
Is there any way I can make it as I've mentioned?

My code:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const number = 3;
const axios = require("axios");

async function fetchData() {
  for (let i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
    const query = axios
      .post(
        "https://graphql.anilist.co",
        {
          query: `query character(
                    $id: Int
                    $page: Int
                    $sort: [MediaSort]
                    $onList: Boolean
                    $withRoles: Boolean = false
                  ) {
                    Character(id: $id) {
                      id
                      name {
                        first
                        middle
                        last
                        full
                        native
                        userPreferred
                        alternative
                        alternativeSpoiler
                      }
                      image {
                        large
                      }
                      favourites
                      isFavourite
                      isFavouriteBlocked
                      description
                      age
                      gender
                      bloodType
                      dateOfBirth {
                        year
                        month
                        day
                      }
                      media(page: $page, sort: $sort, onList: $onList) @include(if: $withRoles) {
                        pageInfo {
                          total
                          perPage
                          currentPage
                          lastPage
                          hasNextPage
                        }
                        edges {
                          id
                          characterRole
                          voiceActorRoles(sort: [RELEVANCE, ID]) {
                            roleNotes
                            voiceActor {
                              id
                              name {
                                userPreferred
                              }
                              image {
                                large
                              }
                              language: languageV2
                            }
                          }
                          node {
                            id
                            type
                            isAdult
                            bannerImage
                            title {
                              userPreferred
                            }
                            coverImage {
                              large
                            }
                            startDate {
                              year
                            }
                            mediaListEntry {
                              id
                              status
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }`,
          variables: {
            id: i,
            withRoles: false,
          },
        },
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        // console.log(response.data.data.Character)
        const jsonContent =
          JSON.stringify(response.data.data.Character, null, 4) + ", ";

        fs.appendFile("./chars.json", jsonContent, function (err) {
          if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
          }

          console.log("The file was saved!");
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(`Code: ${error}`, error));
  }
}

fetchData();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that will work for you (Asuming all the rest was ok):

```
const delay = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

async function fetchData() {
  for (let i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
    // So in case your function is called in loop - request will be delayed
    await delay(5000); // TODO: Change to whatever you need
    const query = axios.post(
      "https://graphql.anilist.co",
      {
        query: someQuery, // TODO: Set your query here
        variables: { id: i, withRoles: false }
      },
      {
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
      }
    );

    try {
      const response = await query;
      const jsonContent = JSON.stringify(response.data.data.Character, null, 4) + ", ";

      fs.appendFile("./chars.json", jsonContent, function (err) {
        if (err) {
          return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("The file was saved!");
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(`Code: ${e}`, e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: await delay(1000); breaks, when it returns 404 and mass requests the api and gets it rate-limited.

Comment: @Korih Try to add await delay(5000); just before `return` in try catch block. Or move await delay to the first line after for loop starts. Probably that is because catch block's return statement, but return had to return from this function and no other loops should happen. Do you have any other loop over this function?

Comment: Thank you so much again! I've added a condition to check since it was only returning undefined for both 404 and 429 status codes.